# С чем может быть связана ошибка?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor

Стабильно появляется ошибка в ubuntu. При сборке внутри docker

```
> bson-ext@0.1.13 install /app/node_modules/bson-ext
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/app/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
bson.target.mk:109: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/bson-ext/build'

> kerberos@0.0.24 install /app/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/app/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
In file included from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:0:
../lib/kerberos.h:5:27: fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gssapi/gssapi.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 1
kerberos.target.mk:115: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.3.0-42-generic
gyp ERR! command "/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
gyp ERR! not ok

> ursa@0.9.4 install /app/node_modules/ursa
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/app/node_modules/ursa/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:192:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:10,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function 'Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)':
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:15: error: 'class v8::Object' has no member named 'ForceSet'
   return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
               ^
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:59:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:197,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:10,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h: In static member function 'static Nan::imp::ToFactoryBase<v8::Boolean>::return_t Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Boolean>::convert(v8::Local<v8::Value>)':
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18:69: warning: 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Boolean> v8::Value::ToBoolean(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:2663): ToBoolean can never throw. Use Local version. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       val->To ## TYPE(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()->GetCurrentContext())          \
                                                                     ^
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: note: in expansion of macro 'X'
 X(Boolean)
 ^
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h: In static member function 'static Nan::imp::ValueFactoryBase<bool>::return_t Nan::imp::ToFactory<bool>::convert(v8::Local<v8::Value>)':
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:37:57: warning: 'v8::Maybe<bool> v8::Value::BooleanValue(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:2701): BooleanValue can never throw. Use Isolate version. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return val->NAME ## Value(isolate->GetCurrentContext());                     \
                                                         ^
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:40:1: note: in expansion of macro 'X'
 X(bool, Boolean)
 ^
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:198,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:10,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function 'static Nan::imp::FactoryBase<v8::Function>::return_t Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Function>::New(Nan::FunctionCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>)':
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:105:32: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Function::New(v8::Isolate*&, void (&)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Object>&)'
                           , obj));
                                ^
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:105:32: note: candidate is:
In file included from /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:9,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:4275:31: note: static v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Function> v8::Function::New(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::FunctionCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, int, v8::ConstructorBehavior, v8::SideEffectType)
   static MaybeLocal<Function> New(
                               ^
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:4275:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'v8::Isolate*' to 'v8::Local<v8::Context>'
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:198,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:10,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function 'static Nan::imp::FactoryBase<v8::StringObject>::return_t Nan::imp::Factory<v8::StringObject>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>)':
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:37: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::StringObject::New(v8::Local<v8::String>&)'
   return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                     ^
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:37: note: candidate is:
In file included from /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:9,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:5531:23: note: static v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::StringObject::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>)
   static Local<Value> New(Isolate* isolate, Local<String> value);
                       ^
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:5531:23: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:198,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:10,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:58: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                                          ^
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:60: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
   return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                                            ^
In file included from ../src/ursaNative.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)':
../../nan/nan.h:835:60: warning: 'v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:173): Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, func, argc, argv);
                                                            ^
../../nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)':
../../nan/nan.h:850:62: warning: 'v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:166): Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, symbol, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
../../nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)':
../../nan/nan.h:865:62: warning: 'v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:159): Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, method, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
../../nan/nan.h: In constructor 'Nan::Utf8String::Utf8String(v8::Local<v8::Value>)':
../../nan/nan.h:911:53: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Value::ToString()'
       v8::Local<v8::String> string = from->ToString();
                                                     ^
../../nan/nan.h:911:53: note: candidates are:
In file included from /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:9,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:2668:44: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
                                            ^
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:2668:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
                 from /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:27,
                 from /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:9,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:2684:31: note: v8::Local<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString(v8::Isolate*) const
                 Local<String> ToString(Isolate* isolate) const);
                               ^
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:2684:31: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
                 Local<String> ToString(Isolate* isolate) const);
                               ^
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
In file included from ../src/ursaNative.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan.h:921:74: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::String::WriteUtf8(char*&, int, int, const int&)'
         length_ = string->WriteUtf8(str_, static_cast<int>(len), 0, flags);
                                                                          ^
../../nan/nan.h:921:74: note: candidate is:
In file included from /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.h:9,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:2878:7: note: int v8::String::WriteUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char*, int, int*, int) const
   int WriteUtf8(Isolate* isolate, char* buffer, int length = -1,
       ^
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:2878:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char*' to 'v8::Isolate*'
In file included from ../src/ursaNative.h:10:0,
                 from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
../../nan/nan.h: In member function 'v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call_(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const':
../../nan/nan.h:1479:5: warning: 'v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/node.h:173): Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ));
     ^
../../nan/nan.h: In member function 'void Nan::AsyncWorker::SaveToPersistent(const char*, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)':
../../nan/nan.h:1533:64: warning: 'bool v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:3498): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     New(persistentHandle)->Set(New(key).ToLocalChecked(), value);
                                                                ^
../../nan/nan.h: In member function 'void Nan::AsyncWorker::SaveToPersistent(const v8::Local<v8::String>&, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)':
../../nan/nan.h:1539:42: warning: 'bool v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:3498): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     New(persistentHandle)->Set(key, value);
                                          ^
../../nan/nan.h: In member function 'void Nan::AsyncWorker::SaveToPersistent(uint32_t, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)':
../../nan/nan.h:1545:44: warning: 'bool v8::Object::Set(uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:3507): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     New(persistentHandle)->Set(index, value);
                                            ^
../../nan/nan.h: In member function 'v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::AsyncWorker::GetFromPersistent(const char*) const':
../../nan/nan.h:1551:61: warning: 'v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Value>)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.1.k3wg3l.4aco++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/v8.h:3553): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         New(persistentHandle)->Get(New(key).ToLocalChecked()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в новой версии meteor 1.9 - 1.10 (видимо из-за новой версии встроенной node js).
На версии 1.8.3 ошибок нет